# Onclick Submit form Javascript with image buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

hey, well I have this form

```
    <form method="POST" action=''>
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="download1">
<input type="hidden" name="usr_login" value="<TMPL_VAR usr_login>">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<TMPL_VAR file_code>">
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="<TMPL_VAR file_name>">
<input type="hidden" name="referer" value="<TMPL_VAR referer>">
<div class="premium-download"><input name="method_premium" value="<TMPL_VAR lang_premium_download>" type="image" src="images/premium-download.png" alt="<TMPL_VAR lang_premium_download>" border="0" /></div>
<div class="free-download"><input name="method_free" value="<TMPL_VAR lang_free_download>" type="image" src="images/free-download.png" alt="<TMPL_VAR lang_free_download>" /></div>
</form>
```

How can I submit the form from the image inputs (see the last two fields)?  Right now they are set as image type and I understand that those will not submit the form by default. Could anyone help? I was told to do it with javascript :D

Comment: The assumption is incorrect. The "image" type submits the form. You don't have an "action" though so that may be your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I initially misread your question.  As already noted, `<input type="image">` elements *do* submit forms.  However, if you're looking for more versatility than image inputs, my answer still applies.

---

> I was told to do it with javascript

Don't, use `<button>` elements instead.  `<button>` elements work like `<input type="button">`, except that they can be styled to have no border, be transparent, and they can contain other HTML.  For example:

```
<button type="submit" name="method_premium" value="<TMPL_VAR lang_premium_download>">
  <img src="images/premium-download.png" alt=alt="<TMPL_VAR lang_premium_download>" />
</button>
```

Style the button with CSS (`border:none; background-color:transparent;`) and you're good to go.

> Buttons created with the `BUTTON` element function just like buttons created with the `INPUT` element, but they offer richer rendering possibilities: the `BUTTON` element may have content. For example, a `BUTTON` element that contains an image functions like and may resemble an `INPUT` element whose type is set to "image", but the `BUTTON` element type allows content.

- [The *BUTTON* Element - W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5)

Answer (score 1):

Input elements with "type" set to "image" do indeed act (almost) exactly like "submit" inputs. It's "almost" exactly because you also get the coordinates of the mouse click, and you **don't** get the "value" of the input element.

If you wanted the clicks on the "image" inputs to submit the values, the simplest thing to do would be to have a couple more hidden inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but you could submit the form using JavaScript. It might be best to use the BUTTON as suggested by @Andy E:

```
<form method="POST" name='myForm'>   
...
...


<script lang="javascript">
function SubmitForm()
{
  document.forms['myForm'].submit() ;
}
</script>
```